# Placing a function inside of another function not working

Tags: javascript, html, closures

I'm trying to have text display one letter at a time. I have a working version that is not inside of a function. I'd like to place it all into a function, however I'm having trouble getting it to work. When placed into a function, I'm getting an issue where it says ".split" is not a function.

Working Version Outside of Function

```
let text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.'

const textArray = text.split('');
let loopTimer;

const frameLooper = () => {
    textArray.length > 0 ? document.querySelector('#text').innerHTML += textArray.shift() : clearTimeout(loopTimer);
    loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()', 30);
}

frameLooper()
```

---

Inside of function (Not working)

```
    let dialog = (text) => {
        let textArray = text.split('');
        return textArray;
    }
    
    let loopTimer
    
    const frameLooper = (text) => {
        let array = dialog(text)
        array.length > 0 ? document.querySelector('#text').innerHTML += array.shift() : clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()', 30);
    }
    
    frameLooper(dialog('This is a test'))
```

---

Here is the HTML in the event it's needed:

```
        <p id="text" class="text-red-200"></p>

    </div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout('frameLooper()'` you are passing it no arguments, but the function requires an argument

Comment: avoid passing a string to `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother about manipulating the array - just access the elements from a `setTimeout` loop.

```js
// Cache the element
const div = document.querySelector('#text');

function frameLooper(str) {

  // Split the string
  const arr = str.split('');

  // Create a small loop for the `setTimeout` to call
  // Set the index to 0
  function loop(i = 0) {

    // If the index is less than the array length
    // add a letter from the array
    if (i < arr.length) div.textContent += arr[i];

    // Otherwise increase the index, and run the loop again
    setTimeout(loop, 100, ++i);

  }

  loop();

}

// Pass in the string
frameLooper('This is a test');
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. You were able to solve my issue. Much appreciated! Also, I noticed I got down voted. Was there something I did incorrectly with the post? (For the record, I tried doing research for a few hours but was unable to find a resolution until your post). I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I'm still learning.

Comment: You wrote a very good question IMO. I'm sorry you got downvoted. You tried to debug your code, and you asked for help - but most importantly you put the work in. I'm glad I could help. Welcome to SO. This site can be a bit fickle. Hope your coding goes well.

Comment: Ah I see. Well at least it wasn't me doing something wrong with the post then. Thanks again! Have a good one! (I would up vote your post but I'm not allowed yet it says. I was able to accept it as the answer though at least)